# Gitkit Error MODE_MISSING: "mode"on Safari

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

My Python/Django project works with Gitkit on Chrome but Safari give me the following error on both MaxOS/iOS and do not displays the account chooser:

```
Error MODE_MISSING: "mode" parameter was missing in the widget URL.  Dismiss
```

Does anyone have a suggestion? Is there anything I should do just for Safari?

Answer (score 2):

You widget page should have a mode url parameter:
http://localhost/widget?mode=select

Comment: I don't really understand where I should add this parameter and also, if it is missing, why it does work perfectly on Google Chrome for MacOS, Linux, Android and iOS? Can you explain better?

Comment: The widget page has multiple modes. It could be rendering in manage account mode, email change, or password reset mode, etc. It needs to know the selected mode. You just have to pass the ?mode=select url parameter in the widget page where you are seeing that error.